# Workfront- Tagging User in Notes via the API

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I'd like to create a project-level note that tags a user via the Workfront API. I can create the note:

`https://[SUBDOMAIN].attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v5.0/note?noteText=[MESSAGE_TEXT]&noteObjCode=PROJ&objID=[PROJECT_ID]&sessionID=[SESSION_ID]&method=POST`

But I'm struggling to figure out the syntax to tag a user. I've tried the following:

`https://[SUBDOMAIN].attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v5.0/note?noteText=[MESSAGE_TEXT]&noteObjCode=PROJ&objID=[PROJECT_ID]&tags:objID=[USER_ID]&tags:objObjCode=USER&sessionID=[SESSION_ID]&method=POST`

But I get a

`APIModel V5_0 does not support field tags:objID (Note)`

message returned.

I *think* that it's some combination of the "ntag" or "tags" object I need to add, but not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are updating the Tags collection you need to do it through an updates using JSON instead of just sending URL parameters.
The way you do this is the following.

```
api/v5.0/note?updates={ "noteText":"this is an update", "noteObjCode":"PROJ", "objID":"574f32a400333f3d00d8a0e3e5495eb2", "tags":[{"objID":"5594243d02461f451395a9d24d1639e1","objObjCode":"USER"}]}
```